# Is there a way to get IsHighlighted in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I thought there is Button.IsHighlighted, but it doesn't exist. I tried EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject (saw on official unity forum), but it doesn't work to. What should I do?

Comment: There's [three (3) different UI systems in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/UI-system-compare.html), which one are you using?

Comment: i guess runtime in-game (runtime only)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is some out-of-the-box property for this, but you can handle this situation using [`OnPointEnter` and `OnPointExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) methods

Comment: it doesn't work, but i can send a video,i may did something wrong

Comment: @abibasich _["Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)_